# Naming Convention for constant Acronyms

Tags: c#, naming-conventions, stylecop, acronym

Naming convention according to StyleCop for constants is Pascal.

For example

```
private const double InchToMm= 2.54;
```

What about naming convention for acronym?

```
private const int Dpi = 96;
```

or

```
private const int DPI = 96;
```

Comment: I personally capitalise my constants, it's something I've done since leaving university and most developers I've worked with have done similar

Comment: `DPI` is abbreviation, which become a word `dpi` (used commonly). Therefore using `Dpi` is more natural (it's common style). As opposed to when you innovate your own abbreviation, e.g. `The Best Value`, then you must use `TBV` for such constant (`Tbv` would be bad idea).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Framework Design Guidelines](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321545613) from Microsoft says:

> The PascalCasing convention, used for all identifiers except parameter
>   names, capitalizes the first character of each word (including
>   acronyms over two letters in length), as shown in the following
>   examples:
>
> `PropertyDescriptor`
>
> `HtmlTag`
>
> A special case is made for two-letter acronyms in which both letters
>   are capitalized, as shown in the following identifier:
>
> `IOStream`
>
> The camelCasing convention, used only for parameter names, capitalizes
>   the first character of each word except the first word, as shown in
>   the following examples. As the examples also shows, two-letter
>   acronyms that begin a camel-cased identifier are both lowercase:
>
> `propertyDescriptor`
>
> `ioStream`
>
> `htmlTag`

But nevertheless, these are guidelines and conventions and not laws. If you like to take another convention, just use it. But then always and never mix up.

Comment: If we are looking at the Microsoft example, we can see they use capital letters for constants. It is contrasting their own guideline:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.intptr.zero(v=vs.110).aspx
Is it any reason for it?

Comment: @ehh: There are dozens of counter examples in the .Net framework, where a developer didn't stick to the guidelines. Sometimes they had a good reason, sometimes not. In the mentioned book, some of the prominent Microsoft guys show you some of them in their annotations within the book. And sometimes all they can say is: "Sorry, when we seen this error it was already to late to repair it, due to backward compatibility".

Comment: Thank you @Oliver for your explanation

Answer (score 2):

If you go your own route, this is somewhat subjective, but hopefully the rationale is not. The easiest `UpperCamelCase` standard I've found for teams to follow *consistently*, if *consistency* is your primary stylistic goal, is `Dpi`. I'm not saying that's my favorite or the most readable or anything like that.

I'm saying it's the easiest standard to apply consistently for a disparate team of people, and even on your own across the years during which you use this convention. The reason for that is that it's fairly robotic and requires little thought. The way to do it is to ask yourself how you would write this in underscore convention. Would you write like this?

```
d_p_i
```

... If so, you translate the first of each group of characters separated by an underscore into an upper case. That yields `DPI`. But probably almost everyone would write it like this in underscore convention:

```
dpi
```

... so the robotic, unambiguous translation from underscore to `UpperCamelCase` becomes `Dpi`. Same kind of thing if we have:

```
renderer_gl
```

... the robotic, unambiguous translation from underscore would be `RendererGl`.

Now the benefit of this isn't necessarily that it's pretty or closest to how humans would read and write it. It's just that, provided you can settle on how to write the identifier in underscore (which most people do consistently), even a robot can then convert it to `UpperCamelCase` or `lowerCamelCase` without any ambiguity.

So if a strong aesthetic among your team is consistency and having a convention where two different people won't be tempted to use different casing, this can be the easiest way to achieve it.  In our case consistency was a top goal since we provide a software development kit and we didn't want our API to be inconsistent. For that it helped to establish a no-brainer way of choosing how to use `CamelCase` that wouldn't require a lot of thought or involve any form of ambiguity.

With other conventions, often you find a lot of special cases for abbreviations/acronyms. *"If it's a common acronym, treat it like a word. If it's not, treat it like an acronym (all caps). If it's 2 letters in length, treat it like an acronym. If it's 3+ letters in length, treat it like a word. If there's an L or M at the end, treat it like a word, otherwise an acronym unless it's followed by a number or preceded by a proper noun. If it doesn't look good, do it the other way."* The brain can go kablooey here, and teams can fail hard in being able to apply such standards consistently.

Of course consistency may not be your strongest goal, but if it is, I would suggest this convention.

Answer (score 1):

The only StyleCop rule I can find on constants is [SA1303](http://www.stylecop.com/docs/SA1303.html). It states:

> The name of a constant C# field must begin with an upper-case letter.

So either `Dpi` or `DPI` would fit that rule.

[Microsoft says](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229043(v=vs.110).aspx) you should Pascal case it. In my opinion constants should be all uppercase, so I would go for `DPI`. Microsoft uses `Xml` in namespace names, which should be Pascal cased too, so `Dpi` would be most in line with Microsofts own use of naming conventions.